# PSTricks plot random points in polar coordinates

Tags: pstricks

I wish to use PSTricks to plot a random point in a disk of radius 2, following a uniform distribution with respect to polar coordinates (making it less dense far away). I tried out the three following, but PSTricks doesn't understand any of them:

```
\SpecialCoor
\psdot( Rand(0,2) ; Rand(0,360) )
\psdot( \pscalculate{Rand*2} ; \pscalculate{Rand*360} )
\psdot( ! Rand 2 mul ; ! Rand 360 mul )
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm sorry, but I don't see how to modify those examples in a way that the density of the scattered points decreases with the distance r.  Do you?
(As far as I can see all examples involve a uniform distribution in a given area, but I need it uniform with respect the to polar coordinates.)

Comment: To put it in plain math: I would like to scatter the points in polar coordinates ( r ; t ) such that r is random in [0,2] and t is random in [0,360].

(Clearly the result will be a cloud of points in a disk of radius 2, with many points in the middle and less near the booundary.)

BTW: Using runit=2 and \degrees=1 my question simplifes to ( r ; t ) such that r and t are both random in [0,1], independently.  The problem is that PSTricks does understand 
(! Rand Rand )
and does not understand neither
( Rand , Rand )
nor
( Rand ; Rand )

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following template. The explanation is given after it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\pstVerb
{
    realtime srand 
    /RMax 5 def
    /AMax 360 def
}

\begin{document}
\psLoop{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\curvepnodes[plotpoints=100]{0}{360}{RMax Rand mul AMax Rand mul PtoC}{A}
\pscircle{!RMax}
%\foreach \i in {0,1,...,99}{\psline[linecolor=lightgray](0,0)(A\i)}
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,99}{\pscircle*[linecolor=red](A\i){2pt}}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

- `\pstVerb{...}` : identifiers that are valid only in PostScript context.
- `realtime srand` : seeding PSTricks' pseudo-random generator.
- `RMax` : maximum radius
- `AMax` : maximum angle
- `\psLoop{... integer number ...}{... PSTricks objects ...}` : looping construct
- `\curvepnodes{... start ...}{...  stop ...}{... coordinate expression in RPN ...}{... Node ...}`  : defining nodes on a curve
- `Rand` : producing a random floating point number between 0 and 1.
- `RMax Rand mul` : equals to a random floating point between 0 and `RMax`.
- `AMax Rand mul` : equals to a random floating point between 0 and `AMax`.
- `r t PtoC` : converting polar to cartesian
- `!` : RPN prefix for parameter that does not receive RPN by default.

For any question, give comments!

## Extra

If you need to learn how `PtoC` works, see the following. The new verb `MOP`
converts polar to cartesian as `PtoC` does.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\pstVerb
{
 /MOP {2 copy cos mul 3 1 roll sin mul} bind def
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psdots(!5 0 MOP)(!5 90 MOP)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that there is no warning if your own PostScript verbs conflict with the existing ones. As a rule of thumb, always use at least 3 upper case letters.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, MOP!!  Your solutions works and, as a give-away, it contained the little answer that I was looking for:  the command

```
                             PtoC
```

that transforms a polar couple to a cartesian couple.  If you had only revealed to me those secret four letters, I could have done it all by my own ;-)

Here now comes my little plot program:

```
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=2cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)\SpecialCoor
\psframe[framearc=0,linecolor=black,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](-2,-2)(2,2)
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linewidth=1.1pt](0,0){2}
\psLoop{2500}{\psdot[dotscale=.25](! 2 Rand mul 360 Rand mul PtoC)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Modern people never need to invoke `\SpecialCoor` because it is already enabled by default since 20xx (I forgot).

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=4cm}
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
\psRandom[dotsize=1pt,fillstyle=solid](1,1){\pscircle (0.5,0.5){0.5}}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
\psRandom[randInit=42,dotsize=2pt,randomPoints=5000,color, 
  fillstyle=solid](1,1){\pscircle(0.5,0.5){0.5}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]